# Free alternative for paint tool SAI

Tags: software-recommendation, drawing, free, sai

I've been looking for a freeware alternative for Paint Tool SAI.

What I've been looking for is the editable curved/straight lines that you draw in Paint Tool SAI. It's a whole new level of convenience when drawing using a mouse.

Comment: I never used SAI so can you describe with more details what's so good about drawing lines in it? How is that different from Illustrator or Inkscape, for example?

Comment: I think is simmilar as drawing first a path and then aplying a brush stroke.

Comment: thank you all for the reply. though it differs in a way with SAI, i've found gimp as an alternative. thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are refering to drawing first a path and then aplying a brush stroke:

I have not tested in depth but looks promising.

MediBang Paint
https://medibangpaint.com/en/ You can use a vector path as a guide for passing a raster brush o top of it.

But if you are refering simply for a tool to draw and paint you can look at MyPaint http://mypaint.org/

Or the free version of dogwaffle http://www.thebest3d.com/dogwaffle/free/
There is an extension which I have not used that uses spinlines to smooth strokes: http://www.thebest3d.com/dogwaffle/penny/index.html (from time to time they release one free version of Artist)

All depends hevely of using a tablet to achive the faded look on the brush strokes.

The other well known free aplications are Inkscape and Gimp, which you can probably adapt to your workflow.

But if you are familiar with Paint Tool SAI, it is probably a good idea to save some bucks and buy it.